# JSF - rich:tabPanel - A backing bean property is called for each tab and not for the active one only

Tags: jsf, tabs, richfaces, javabeans

I have **15 tabs** containing a similar table, so I have only **one backing bean collection of items** defining my table. When the tab changes, the collection changes accordingly. So, **when the tab is rendered**, I am expecting the get method of my collection to be called only once, for my active tab because on screen and in the DOM this tab is the only one with a table. BUT, **the get method of my collection is called 15 times**, which I guess is because I have 15 tabs.

How do you explain that ? Here is my code.

```
<rich:tabPanel activeItem="#{myBean.selectedTab}" itemChangeListener="#{myBean.changeItems}" >

    <c:forEach items="#{myBean.tabs}" var="t">

        <rich:tab id="tab_#{t.code}" header="#{t.libelle}" name="#{t.code}" >

            <!--  ############ HEADER ############ -->
            <rich:dataTable id="tableHeader_#{t.code}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <rich:columnGroup>
                       <!-- Some columns. Let's say that I have a button like a sort 
                            with a render attribute set to "tab_#{t.code}"
                            Then all will be correctly rendered but 
                            the get of my collection would have been called 15 times -->
                   </rich:columnGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </rich:dataTable>

            <!--  ############ DATA ############ -->
            <rich:dataTable id="tableData_#{t.code}" value="#{myBean.collectionOfItems}" var="i">
                <!-- Some columns -->
            </rich:dataTable>

        </rich:tab>
    </c:forEach>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: 15 iterations = 15 calls. It shouldn't matter how many times the getter is called though.

Comment: It matters because it makes no sense (and I have a problem which I suspect is linked to that) : I may have 15 iterations to construct the tabs but only the active one have a content and thus a dataTable. So getCollectionOfItems should be called once and only once, otherwise there is a problem somewhere.

Comment: Making no sense is not an objective concern. Does it have an impact on your application? `c:forEach` happens before the tabs are rendered but even if your tabs were static the getters might still get called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The generation called 15 because the tab captions should be generated (header facets). But if you want to do something #{myBean.selectedTab} specific check this out (or something like that ):

```
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.tabs}" var="t">
  <c:if test="#{t.equals( myBean.selectedTab )}" >
    ...
  </c:if>
```

Comment: No, if I do that only the active tab will be rendered. It is exactly like if I used a rendered attribrute on the tab tag.

Comment: Furthermore i tried to use a rendered attribute on the dataTable tag but it changes nothing, because as I said, by default the DOM only contains a table for the active tab. The other tabs don't have any child so I really don't get why the get method is called more than once.